# Haskell List comprehension and `group`

Tags: list, haskell, grouping, list-comprehension, higher-order-functions

input:

> funcA [((0,'x'),1),((0,'y'),3),**((1,'y'),3),((1,'z'),3)**,((2,'x'),2),((2,'y'),2)]

output

> [(0, 1, "x"), (0, 3, "y"), **(1, 3, "yz")**, (2, 2, "xy")]

I'm trying to group by starting node and destination node and then `concat` all the edge names(values such as `'x'`,`'y'`...). So the output order is `[(start, end, "concat val"), ...]`

How can I write the `funcA` in the Haskell language??

I tried `groupBy`, List comprehension, `map` function in it but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: What should output from `funcA [((0,'a'),0),((1,'b'),1),((0,'c'),0)]`? I'm wondering if the values that need to be grouped are always adjacent in the input list.

Comment: I yep true, so, I need to sort it first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define `funcA` as:

```
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.List (groupBy)

funcA :: Eq a => [((a,b),a)] -> [(a,a,[b])]
funcA =
  map (\s@(((x,y),_):_) -> (x, y, map snd s))
  . groupBy ((==) `on` fst)
  . map (\((x,v),y) -> ((x,y),v))
```

Given the list: `[((0,'x'),1),((0,'y'),3),((1,'y'),3),((1,'z'),3),((2,'x'),2),((2,'y'),2)]`

- The `map` at the end of the chain joins the coordinates into a tuple:

  `[((0,1),'x'),((0,3),'y'),((1,3),'y'),((1,3),'z'),((2,2),'x'),((2,2),'y')]`
- The `groupBy` groups on coordinates:

  `[[((0,1),'x')],[((0,3),'y')],[((1,3),'y'),((1,3),'z')],[((2,2),'x'),((2,2),'y')]]`
- The first `map` combines characters with the same coordinate to strings with that coordinate.

Comment: `map (\ s@(((x,y),_):_) -> (x, y, map snd s))` should do the job too.

Comment: (the main thing that was irritating to me there was the zeroes in `(0,0,[])`. if anything, `undefined`s should've been used. but of course as written, that fold just re-implements the `map`.)

Comment: @WillNess: Thanks for the feedback. You are right the `(0,0,[])` is ugly. Your suggestion to use `map snd` etc. is much better. I have updated accordingly.

Comment: ... and it could now work with any `Eq` type, not just `Int` or `(Num,Eq)`. :)

Comment: @WillNess: Thanks, did that as well. :-)